# How do I get a div that's split into two parts not have on part take up blank space?

Tags: html, css

So I'm doing a project for school where I need to make a website but integrating a database. This is using a website from a previous project. I am writing in PHP/HTML.
My previous website had a main div that is split into two parts, one for text, another for an image. The code looks like this:

```
.main {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "text image";
    grid-gap: 4px;
}
```

This worked great for my previous webiste, but now, I want some pages to have images and some to not.
However, when I don't put anything in the image div, even not having it in the page's HTML, I end up with a large amount of space on the side where it would have been.

How could I fix this?

(Sorry for the newbie question, I'm new to coding. Also, I can provide an image if anyone needs it.)

Comment: Check whether an image exists in the row, and print out just a text container if one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understood, your HTML page is having blank space on the right side of the text if the image is not present in the .main div.

Here you can solve this problem by using JavaScript code.

you just have to check whether an image div is present in the main div or not and then remove main class from main div.

follow the below plnkr example for more details on JavaScript method =>
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXmj47w2IscByQcz?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

```
let removeRightSpace = function(){
var allMainDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
for(let i=0; i<allMainDivs.length; i++){
let d = allMainDivs[i];
if(d.getElementsByClassName("image").length < 1){
   console.log(d.classList); d.classList.remove("main");
    console.log(d.classList);
  }
}
};
removeRightSpace();
```

Hope this will solve your issue.